# Is there any trick to cleaning up after grating frozen butter?

Tags: cleaning, butter, grating

I grated frozen butter for the first time today, to make a streusel topping. It worked much faster than my usual method of cubing and cutting in. However the cleanup felt wrong.

I used a paper towel and spatula to get the butter bits off the grater as best I could. But when that stopped making progress, there was still a lot of butter stuck in the crevasses and smeared on the flat parts of the grater. It was easy to wash it with hot water and soap, but it felt like a lot of fat to run down the kitchen sink. It probably would have come clean in the dishwasher as well.

If I had a little more foresight, I think freezing the grater itself beforehand would have made a big difference in preventing the mess.

Is there another method to avoid clogging your pipes? Or is this trick best left to a professional kitchen with a grease trap?

Comment: Normally if you're grating frozen butter, very little of it sticks to the grater.  Is your kitchen really warm?

Comment: Not particularly warm, no. Perhaps I just hadn't left it in the freezer long enough. How long does it take for butter to go from fridge to frozen?

Comment: A few hours, depending.

Comment: My first thought was to submerge the grater in a vessel filled with hot water, to melt the butter and let it float to the surface, to be skimmed off. However, I tried this on a small scale before posting an answer and found that you need to make sure you have enough hot water to really melt the butter, or you actually make more of a mess (if you don’t have enough, the water cools down such that it fails to melt the butter and then you have a mix of warm-but-not-liquid butter still stuck to the item now sitting in a warm-ish bowl of water).  Would not exactly recommend that.